# Neo4j batch import __types__ index for Spring Data

Tags: import, indexing, neo4j, spring-data

I have a problem with initial data import to use Spring Data in future. I *use Neo4j (CSV) Batch Importer* (https://github.com/jexp/batch-import). The main problem is in '**__*types*__**' index usage. 
It seems that Spring Data uses 'className' as a key for that index, but the field is called '**__*type*__**'. I tried to declare field **__*type*__**:string:**__*types*__**, but it creates field **__*type*__** and index **__*types*__** with the same key (**__*type*__**) as the field name. 
Is it possible to set 'className' as a key for the index or to change Spring Data behavior to use '**__*type*__**' as index key?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, right now it is not possible to have a different key for the index-field and type value in the compound approach

But you can specify a different index-file, see: 
and provide the file for the the **types** index with a column className and a value of the FQN.

- https://github.com/jexp/batch-import#explicit-indexing
- https://github.com/jexp/batch-import#examples-1

Comment: As far as I understand, I should specify nodeId in nodes_index.csv. Is it possible to provide pairs like "id:int:MyIndex - className"? (So find a node by MyIndex at first, then add it to index __types__). And the second question: is it possible to provide multiple index.csv files for the same index? What I want to do is one className for id:int:MyIndex1, another for id:int:MyIndex2, etc.